# async http request handling

Tags: http, asynchronous, go

I'm trying to handle an HTTP request in Go asynchronously this way:

1. I pass a handler function to the HTTP server
2. In the handler I store the HttpRequest / HttpResponse objects in a slice or a map
3. When returning from the handler function - the response is NOT returned to the client, but the connection remains open
4. When "some" async input received from another source, I take the relevant HttpRequest / HttpResponse objects from memory, write the response and close the connection.

What I aim for is very similar to Jetty-Continuation in Java.

How can I implement such a behaviour in GoLang?

Comment: Could you provide minimal amount of code to describe what exactly you want to achieve? I am (and I pretty sure someone else among SO users) not familiar with `Jetty-Continuation` :-)

Comment: The question is about a general strategy and therefore it needs no code.  It is OK not to be familiar with all the terms.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You do not need this behavior in Go.

Java HTTP servers use threads and if the servlet waits for something it effectively blocks the current thread. Threads are heavy and thread pools are limited.

In Go the HTTP server implementation uses goroutines and if they are waiting they will not block operating system thread. Goroutines are lightweight and scheduled effectively by Go runtime. By effectively scheduling I mean switching when goroutine makes a system call or waits on channel.

Simply speaking, do not try to copy the workaround from Java servlets as the workaround is not needed in Go.

Let's consider a Java servlet, servlets share operating system threads

```
class Slow extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        // stops the thread for a second
        // operating system puts a thread aside and reuses processor
        // it is out of Java control
        // when all pooled HTTP server threads are sleeping no request is served
    }

}
```

and Go HTTP handler, each handler is run in a seperate goroutine

```
func fast(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    time.Sleep(10000 * time.Second) 
    // Go scheduler puts the goroutine aside 
    // and reuses OS thread for handling another request
    // when one second passes the goroutine is scheduled again 
    // and finishes serving request
}
```

**In Go you get what you want by default.**

Comment: Agreed that the solution may be a bit different in Go, with it's lightweight routines. What if I have a client which my receive it's response synchronously, and a service which response asynchronously by sending a callback to it's clients. I want to develop a middleware-service which receives the request from the client, calls the async-service and holds the client's connection till a callback from the async-service is received.

Comment: @Forepick, you let the HTTP handler sit and wait until the response is ready. The handler function is called in its own goroutine, one per request. That's why it's okay to wait.